# Can't run a copy of my Azure VB.NET web on my local Windows-7 desktop

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, windows, visual-studio, azure

Using Visual Studio 2015 Community at both ends (Azure and desktop)

Open .sln at local desktop VS and I get: "..projects in solution were not loaded correctly."

OUTPUT windows:
C:\Primary\PROJECTS\PRAY\pray web : error  : Configuring IIS Express failed with the following error:

Filename: \?\C:\Primary\PROJECTS\PRAY\pray web.vs\config\applicationhost.config
Error: Cannot write configuration file

Comment: Have you tried  after opening Visual Studio with admin privilege.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!
Just had to unencrypt the directory of my vb.net project.

Microsoft, please add this to your test plan for Visual Studio.
And, your error "Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))" is shockingly obscure for a company that 30 years old.
For shame!  This is the 21st Century.  Be elegant, Microsoft, like Apple.

Nevertheless, Microsoft Visual Studio is the best IDE I've used in 35 years; been a loyal fan of it for 20 years.   Guess what?!  It even debugs Linux targets now.  I kid you not.  I tried it myself.  What an IDE!